# c# What is wrong with my loop

Tags: c#, loops, casting

I have a ChaseSelection class which i use in casting my dropdown list objects,

now i am trying to put the the values from the database as a default value in the drop down list, but it does not seem to work, can anyone help? I dont even think my loop runs. Here is my chaseselection class, and also put in the loop below: Thanks

```
    public class ChaseSelectionItems
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }

        public ChaseSelectionItems(string code, string text)
        {
            this.code = code;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.text;
        }
    }


        foreach (ChaseSelectionItems items in drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items)
        {
            if (items.code == _Row.xcs_View)
            {
                drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = items.text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put a break point and see the whats going on in debug

Comment: define "does not seem to work". Do you get a compilation error? An Exception at runtime? (And which one?) Does it throw no exception but it does not behave in the way you were expecting?

Comment: Which UI framework do you use? WPF, WinForms, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear how you configured the listbox but most likely you did not configure ValueMember correctly. The following might fix that:

```
  foreach (ChaseSelectionItems items in drpdwnChaseSecSelection.Items)
    {
        if (items.code == _Row.xcs_View)
        {
            // drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedValue = items.text;
            drpdwnChaseSecSelection.SelectedItem = items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this does not run either. it does not enter the loop i think

Comment: The loop will not run by itself. Show the surrounding method and how/where you call that.